# How can I create a custom control using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikit

What *are* custom controls, and how do you actually create them using the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread [How build a custom control in Xcode for the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499494/how-build-a-custom-control-in-xcode-for-the-iphone-sdk/499564#499564)