# Thinner UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, height, uitoolbar

How can I create a thinner UIToolBar in my iOS-app? The standard size is 44px, and I would like to have it in 30 or 35px.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing its frame, but I suspect the best way is to subclass it and override its drawRect method.  Other than that you could invent your own UIView subclass for a thin toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a custom UIView that you'll need to create.

[See This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499494/how-build-a-custom-control-in-xcode-for-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to change the height of UIToolbar. You could create your own custom toolbar or if you're feeling lazy use an image that looks like one.

In landscape mode, I believe the toolbar height gets smaller automatically, but this is a fixed size.

Comment: You can change the height of UIToolBar. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135407/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-height-of-a-uitoolbar